# Make PDF pages display side by side when opened in the browser (Two-Up)

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a report in PDF format that I need to add to a website. When a user clicks the link to the report it will open the PDF in their browser. I need pages in the report to be displayed side by side, like a book, with the cover displayed as a single page. I know this can be done in Adobe Acrobat by navigating to `Document Properties > Initial View > Page layout > Two-Up Continuous (Cover Page)`. However, this setting does not appear to effect how the PDF is rendered in the browser, where it remains in a single-page layout.

Is it possible to use a Two-Up layout in the browser?